# Seeking text of a notice published by the Malbim

Tags: history, rabbis, messiah, allegory-mashal

Someone told the following story today (or something like the following story. I may be remembering it incorrectly to some extent). He said he had gotten it from a book called *Em Habanim S'mecha*, which reported it second- (or more-than-second-) hand itself.

> The *Malbim*, while a rabbi in Bucharest, wrote in his commentary to *Daniyel* a strong allusion to when *mashiach* would come. Other rabbis were upset with him, as it's improper to reveal that date: *Yaakov* didn't. [See *Rashi* at the start of *Vay'chi*.] He published a *kol kore* (public notice) in his own defense, which ran roughly as follows:
>
> > There was a boy in Bucharest who prepared well and delivered well a speech in honor of his becoming a *bar mitzva*, and to reward him his father decided to take him on his (the father's) next trip to Leipzig. One day into the journey, the child asked when they would arrive; the father silenced him with a stern look. Some three weeks later, the father asked the wagoner when they'd arrive, and was told "tomorrow". The child asked his father why he had been silenced, yet his father later asked the same question. The father replied that after all the farewells and tears, he should have known it's a long trip, so shouldn't have asked after one day; but after all the journey, it's a reasonable question. Likewise here: *Yaakov* was at the start of the *galus*, an inappropriate time to reveal the time of *mashiach*. But after all the journey, it's appropriate.

Is a copy of the *kol kore*, or of its text, available anywhere? (The person who told me the story told me also that *Em Habanim S'mecha* does not include the text.)

Comment: I wonder if it's in Iaacov Geller's "haMalbim uma'avako im hareformim bebucharest"

Comment: Curiously, though Geller doesn't mention the Kol Koreh, he brings the story in the name of Rabbi Maimon in Sarei Ha'meah. There, Rabbi Maimon brings it in the name of his father. According to Rabbi Maimon's father, when asked by his students why he calculated the ketz, Malbim related to them this story - but about *himself and his own father*, when he was eight and his father took him to Leipzig (shortly before his father passed away).

Comment: In "פון אונזער אלטען אוצר - בראשית", pp. 272-273, published in the 30's, the author, [B. Yoshson](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91._%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F) brings this story in the name of one of the Malbim's students. Search מלבים [here](http://www.ajournal.org/generic.asp?ID=5210), though this site omits the mention of in whose name this was heard. It's in Yiddish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed quoted in full in Eim Habanim Smeichah, pp. [135](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38319&pgnum=146)-136. He says that the original is "in the museum of the community of Prague," but I highly doubt that's still the case.

Comment: Thank you! And I see I got some particulars in the _mashal_ wrong and omitted some details of the _nimshal_, so people should check out the original.

Comment: @msh210: perhaps update it so that people who come across this post will have the right information.