# Malbim's Introduction to the Book of Daniel in Hebrew

Tags: sources-mekorot, text, daniel-book-of

I found an article on aish.com, entitled [Moshiach and the World Today](https://www.aish.com/jw/s/48883092.html) which quoted the Malbim as stating the following:

> A father and son traveling a long distance. As they start out, the son
>   begins to ask when they will arrive, and of course the father does not
>   answer. However, as they near the town, the son asks the same
>   question, and this time the father readily answers that it is only a
>   short while before they reach their destination. "So too, as the time
>   of redemption is clearly approaching, we cannot help but notice the
>   signs all around us that foreshadow that redemption. As the end grows
>   nearer, doubts will become smaller, and at the very end, all doubts
>   will be removed... As the time grows closer, uncertainty recedes in
>   the wake of increasingly abundant wisdom.

The only reference they give is *Introduction to the Book of Daniel*. Does anyone know where I can find the Malbim's Introduction to the Book of Daniel in Hebrew online?

Comment: That the citation is correct (i.e., this really does appear in Malbim's intro to Daniel) seems to me the most reasonable explanation for the existence of [a different translation with the same citation](https://torah.org/torah-portion/perceptions-5775-vayechi). That said, I can't seem to find such an intro online, so I'm not really helping you. https://www.hebrewbooks.org/39993 & https://www.sefaria.org.il/Malbim_on_Daniel & https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%22%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C are Malbim on Daniel but none of them has an intro that I see.

Comment: Searching around, I find that R' Yissachar Teichtal הי"ד, in [Eim Habanim Smeicha 2:21](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=38319#p=146), quotes this mashal in the name of the Malbim, but not in an "introduction to Daniel," but in a broadsheet (קול קורא) he published _after_ he had published his commentary to Daniel. (In that commentary he gave an explicit date for Moshiach's coming - which, בעוונותינו הרבים, has long since passed - and contemporary rabbanim objected to that; this broadsheet, with the mashal, was his reply.)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/seeking-text-of-a-notice-published-by-the-malbim